# Array not working correctly

Tags: oracle

I have a function that takes in 1 parameter, abc(parameter1 IN varchar2)

In the parameter I will be taking in a string that is comma delimited:
E.g Abc('1,2,a')

```
Type vartype is varray(10) of varchar2(50);
X1 vartype:= vartype (parameter1);

For X in X1.count loop
    Dbms_output.put_line(x1(X));
End loop;
```

The DBMS Output gives me

```
1,2,a
```

Instead of

```
1 
2
A
```

Is there anyway I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
For my understanding your function parameter will be single value.

If you are mentioned varray, you should give format like ('1','2','a','b')
For example :-
declare
Type vartype is varray(10) of varchar2(50);
X1 vartype:=vartype ('1','2','a','b');
begin
For X in 1..X1.count loop
    Dbms_output.put_line(x1(x));
End loop;
end;
/

Above query will help you to understand concepts of Varray
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `varchar2` variable to the `varray` and it's considered the first paramter; so your array contains only one element (the content of `parameter1`). You must split the string into substring before passing to the varray.
Here is an extract from [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm)

```
DECLARE    TYPE ProjectList IS VARRAY(50) OF VARCHAR2(16);   
    accounting_projects ProjectList;
BEGIN
    accounting_projects :=  ProjectList('Expense Report', 'Outsourcing', 'Auditing'); 
END;
```

For splitting a string into substring you can check some solutions [here](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)